# ViewExpiredException - why different behaviour?

Tags: jsf-2, viewexpiredexception

I have a JSF 2 application and configured the following in `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

For testing purposes I have the following code in a `@SessionScoped` class within an init Method annotated with `@PostConstruct` in order to let the session quickly expire:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ec.getSession(false);
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
```

Now, when I have an `h:commandButton` with `outcome = "somepage.jsf"` then a click after the 5s will redirect to the error page.

When I instead call some bean action or putting the page name in action on the very same button using the `action` attribute , I see the `ViewExpiredException` in the server's log, but no redirection occurs.

Why is that so? And how to generally redirect to another page no matter which action took place after the session expires?

Comment: Is this action been performed by an ajax request? That'd explain the symptoms.

Comment: Yes, there is an `f:axax` involved. But what to do then with the exception, since on the page just nothing happens?

Comment: It should have been `f:ajax`of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is different because an asynchronous (ajax) request is been sent. Ajax requests require a special XML response. Exceptions on ajax requests needs to be handled by either the `jsf.ajax.addOnError` handler in JavaScript or a custom [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html).

By default they have namely no single form of helpful feedback in the client side. Only in Mojarra with project stage set to `Development` you'll see a bare JavaScript alert message with the exception message. But that's it. There is no single form of feedback in `Production` stage.

With a custom `ExceptionHandler` you would be able to simulate exactly the same form of feedback as in synchronous requests. You could parse the `web.xml` to find the proper error page location, create a new `UIViewRoot` around it and force JSF to set ajax rendering to `@all`. Since that's after all relatively quite some work, the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) provides exactly such an exception handler out the box in flavor of [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.html). You can find the showcase page [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler).

Comment: I tried to follow your showcase, but there is still no displaying of the error page. I do see a log message from `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` stating `Error page '/error.html' will be shown.`but it doesn't. My xhtml button looks like that: `<h:commandButton value="Error" action="#{myHandler.raiseError}"><f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" /> </h:commandButton>`. What may be missing?

Comment: Maybe I need to add my runtime environment: Tomcat 7.0.32, JDK 1.6.0_37, Kubuntu Linux 12.10

Comment: It must be a Facelets page, not a plain HTML page. This is not checked, but explicitly mentioned in the javadoc of `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Ok, I missed that point, thank you. I was only thinking that an error page, especially when dealing with RuntimeExceptions should be very basic to avoid again errors in the error.xhtml.

Comment: It can in turn just contain plain HTML though.

Comment: I have to get back to my question - I don't know what causes it, but now the situation is as follows: I have configured the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` and then distinguish between `ViewExpiredException` and error code 500 which each go to a different error page. But now, it only works for an ajax call, but not for an `h:commandButton`. Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: You're not clear as to how exactly it fails, but perhaps you need the [`FacesExceptionFilter`](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/filters/FacesExceptionFilter.xhtml) as well (whose logic the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` also is using under the covers).

Comment: Hey, you are quick for sure...ok, so when I let the view expire (e.g. deleting JSESSIONID) and then click something which calls a method via `f:ajax`, then my page for view expiration gets displayed, which is configured first in `web.xml`for `ViewExpiredException`. When I do the same but clicking something which calls a method or another page directly via `h:commandButton` then I see the general error page which is configured second in `web.xml`for error code 500.

Comment: Hey BalusC, I was surprised by your quickness of the last comment, but haven't heard something back on my addition - can you tell me more about what I may need to do with the more details?

Comment: Yes, I added the part in the web.xml according to my faces servlet name, but still I don't see the page configured for view expiration. I'm sure there is something wrong in the whole conglomerate, but don't know what. On the other hand it's not the first time I ask myself why often achieving basic expected behaviour from a JSF2 Web application is very hard and requires gurus like you...